# WSO2: xml to json data mapping in wso2 esb : json message is wrapped in soap envelope

Tags: json, wso2, datamapper, wso2-esb

I am working on one request where the input message is xml and it has to be converted to json. I am using data mapper to do this.
Configured proxy service for the same and below is the code for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="xmltojson_to_Partneronb" startOnLoad="true" transports="vfs 
http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
<inSequence>
<log level="full">
<property name="property_name" value="Initial reading file"/>
</log>
<datamapper config="gov:datamapper/ProducerPartnerOnb.dmc" inputSchema="gov:datamapper/ProducerPartnerOnb_inputSchema.json" inputType="XML" outputSchema="gov:datamapper/ProducerPartnerOnb_outputSchema.json" outputType="JSON"/>
<log level="full">
<property name="property_name" value="after enriching"/>
</log>
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
</inSequence>
<outSequence/>
<faultSequence/>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.PollInterval">1</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///tmp/in</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///tmp/failure</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.xml</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">file:///tmp/out</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Comment: also these are uncommented in axis2.xml 
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>

Comment: You need to provide details on what issue you are facing.What i see is you have provided your code without any description of the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that :(
The issue is, when I am using this proxy service to pull one xml file and process through data mapper to convert it into json message, it is getting done but the json message is having soap envelopes and it is in xml format only.
Data mapping is happening properly only the issue is the final json message which needs to be sent is having xml structure and soap envelopes.

Comment: Can you paste the log after datamapper, upon that i dont see respond or loopback mediator after you have used the property messagType

Comment: here is the output

Comment: Also, I have added respond mediator now and it gives me below message when executed
Axis2Sender FILE_LENGTH:939,LAST_MODIFIED:1535543231000,FILE_URI:file:///tmp/in/xmltojson.xml,FILE_PATH:/tmp/in/xmltojson.xml,FILE_NAME:xmltojson.xml, Unexpected error sending message back

Comment: INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:1B76DA7541FD1FE6621535617168406, Direction: request, property_name = after enrich, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">; <soapenv:Body><jsonObject> <FirstName>ABC</FirstName><MiddleInitial>m</MiddleInitial><LastName>LN</LastName><Email>test@test.com</Email><Company>Test</Company> <Address1>200 West St</Address1><Address2>hjhjhj</Address2> </jsonObject></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

From the logs which you have provided the SOAP format is not framed correctly, below is the formatted SOAP Response.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   ;
   <soapenv:Body>
      <jsonObject>
         <FirstName>ABC</FirstName>
         <MiddleInitial>m</MiddleInitial>
         <LastName>LN</LastName>
         <Email>test@test.com</Email>
         <Company>Test</Company>
         <Address1>200 West St</Address1>
         <Address2>hjhjhj</Address2>
      </jsonObject>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

After SOAP envelop ends there is a `;` due to which you are getting error, you need to rectify this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: I have checked the code and rectify as well but didnot get the proper results.. is the data mapper is good way to convert the data or shall I go ahead with other mediators like payloadfactory etc...

Comment: It depends on the suitation, if the payload is small then it is recommended to go with payload mediator, if the payload is big or complex then i would recommend to go with XSLT mediator